# Hosting Discord bot via Vultr

Tags: node.js, terminal, bots, discord.js, filezilla

I'm pretty new to coding Discord bots but I made something I wanted to host.

I went to vultr.com and got everything I needed and followed a tutorial in order to get my bot online 24/7.

Everything went smooth until I had to start the bot. Every time I started it, the status was online but when I opened the logs, it gave me this error. I can see that the error is somewhere in the **discord.js** file.

I tried uninstalling and installing discord.js a few times but that didn't work out.

Does anyone know the solution to this error?

```
0|index    | /root/artbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:41
0|index    |     } catch {
0|index    |             ^
0|index    |
0|index    | SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
0|index    |     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
0|index    |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
0|index    |     at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
0|index    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
0|index    |     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
0|index    |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
0|index    |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
0|index    |     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
0|index    |     at Module.Hook._require.Module.require 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:80:39)
0|index    |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. That means that there's a `{` which JS doesn't understand. I looked up the source of discord.js and it's working fine. I think your node version is just outdated, because this catch syntax without a exception type works at node v12 and above.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I said I am new to creating discord bots. What exactly do you mean by source code? The code of my index.js? If so, I used "require" a lot which means I got a lot of other files I'd have to share right?

Comment: @SjulG Because that you're new, I don't assume that you'd split up your code in multiple files. So I assume, I only need the file where you did the coding.

Comment: @Steven2105 When I said 'new', I meant like a few months. I made my bot in a total of 8 files. The index.js and commands in each of the other files. I think that you're asking for the index.js file since all the important code is in there. I'd send my code but it's too large to be send in a comment, how am I suposed to send it?

Comment: You can use something like pastebin or hastebin.

Comment: @Steven2105 Oke, I just tried Pastebin and I think it worked? This should be the code of my index.js

https://pastebin.com/2CBMmeZt

Comment: Well, I don't see any error is that file. `/root/artbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:41 SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. This says that there's a curly brackets error. I looked into that file and there was no error. Could you also send the other files you are using?

Comment: @Steven2105 Oke, I'll add all the code I got for my bot. I'm also using a .env and .env-example file with my bot token in it as well as the general files you need for a discord bot. The weird this is that everything works in Visual Studio code...

mDelete.js: https://pastebin.com/FEBBjikc
reactionAdd: https://pastebin.com/JrvQuKNA
reactionRemove: https://pastebin.com/uPFB36RS
roleSelect: https://pastebin.com/yFD4erm4
suggestions: https://pastebin.com/LUpRGd89
guildmemberAdd: https://pastebin.com/HmjSYyWd
guildmemberLeave: https://pastebin.com/v3fjkgYD

Comment: I've recreated the bot by myself and it works. I informed me about that invalid catch block and found out that this syntax which discord.js uses, is only working with NodeJS version 12 and above. Can you select that version on Vultr?

Comment: @Steven2105 When I typed "nodejs -v" in my terminal, it said that it's on version 8.10.0. I don't know if this version is outdated. If it is, I don't know how to update it to version 12 and above... Could you please help me with that?

Comment: I do not user Vultr because those services are abnormally expensive. So please contact their support for help. If they don't offer that version, you have to manually modify the discord.js library, that could also break other stuff as well. But I do think, that they'd support at least version 12.